# Why is Entity Framework passing a parameter as DECIMAL(5,0) for a column defined with NUMERIC(19)?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, precision, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

A database column is defined as NUMERIC(19) in SQL Server. In <edmx:StorageModels>, the edmx shows:

```
<Property Name="supplier_id" Type="numeric" Nullable="false" Precision="19" />
```

In <edmx:ConceptualModels>, I see it as:

```
<Property Type="Decimal" Name="supplier_id" Nullable="false" Precision="19" Scale="0" />
```

In the database, a SELECT with this column in the WHERE clause comes through with this parameter definition:

```
(@p__linq__0 decimal(5,0))
```

for this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[supplier_id] = @p__linq__0)
```

I understand that numeric and decimal are equivalent, but why is the precision getting changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(@p__linq__0 decimal(5,0))` is the Precision of the parameter value your provided.

**For example,**

```
decimal number = 12345m;
var result = context.MyTables.Where(x => x.Number == number).ToList();
```

Then the query will be like this -

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number]
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Number] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 decimal(5,0)',
    @p__linq__0=12345
```

The answer is SQL Statement doesn't need to be same Precision number for **where clause**.

Entity Framework is smart enough to figure out the Precision of a number, and only creates the query with required Precision.

Note: it is not the case for Insert and Update; EF creates a query with the same Precision as Column.