# Entity Framework - Precision in queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Very similar to this question: [Why is Entity Framework passing a parameter as DECIMAL(5,0) for a column defined with NUMERIC(19)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333529/why-is-entity-framework-passing-a-parameter-as-decimal5-0-for-a-column-defined)

However, the answer given doesn't seem to align with my results.

I have a column, `OrderEntryTimeUtc datetime2(0)` over which the table is partitioned. Now, in order to actually use the partitioning, I need my queries to use the same type and precision.

But when I create my where clause:

```
o.OrderEntryTimeUtc > dateStart
```

where dateStart is a DateTime with the ms part set to 0, I get the following generated parameter:

```
@p__linq__2 datetime2(7)
@p__linq__2='2016-05-21 23:44:33'
```

How can I force EF to send a `datetime2(0)`? Or how can I add a `CONVERT` to my query without having to write the whole query in SQL or create a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modelBuilder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
    .Property(p => p.OrderEntryTimeUtc)
    .HasColumnType("datetime2")
    .HasPrecision(0);
```

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't change the precision of the query parameter.

Comment: @Massanu: Unfortunately, that doesn't change the queries, only the columns. But it would've made a lot more sense if it did.